# Which encryption algorithm EOSIO uses

Tags: cryptography, encryption

As we know Ethereum uses `ECDSA` (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) for its public-key cryptography. Which algorithm EOS uses for encryption?

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin, Ethereum or EOS uses secp256k1 algorithm. Not approximately, but exactly same. You can derive Ethereum address from EOS private key and sign Ethereum transaction. One difference between EOS and others, EOS supports secp256r1 a.k.a prime-256 which is NIST standard and supported by Android or iOS platform libraries. You can find there are two types of key in EOS (K1, R1) and each one indicates secp256k1 or secp256r1.

Comment: Nice answer! Do you have any references or links to appropriate sections of code that show this?

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 I'm sorry, but I don't have a single source of this information. However, you can see all blockchains mentioned, [Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/secp256k1), [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/crypto/secp256k1/libsecp256k1) and [EOS](https://github.com/EOSIO/fc/tree/f4755d330faf9d2342d646a93f9a27bf68ca759e/secp256k1) depend on `libsecp256k1`.

Answer (score 1):

EOS also uses Elliptic curve cryptography for more you can refer https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc

Comment: Does this mean that  Ethereum and EOS use approximately same encryption algorithm?